# How to combine Helvetica and Symbol with LuaTeX?

Tags: fontspec, unicode, unicode-math

For text and equation in figures I want to use the Helvetica font. Unfortunately the greek symbols from Helvetica are not really suitable. A number of publishers recommend to combine Helvetica with the greek symbols from the `Symbol.ttf` font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Helvetica World}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{Helvetica World}  
% this does not work:
%\setmathfont[use greek letters from]{Symbol}

\begin{document}

Some text and an equation: $\alpha + \beta = QR$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I played around with `\DeclareMathSymbol` but that conflicted with unicode-math.

Is there any way to follow this recommendation of combining these two fonts in (Lua-)LaTeX?

Comment: The font used with `\setmathfont` should have an opentype math table which sets many math related parameters. latin modern math, xits math, cambria math have this table for example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That is definitely the best path but often you have to adapt to the environment you work in (e.g. colleagues, publishers,...).

Comment: No the unicode-math package _requires_ that, it was not just a possibly best path, it is the only way it can work. It is possible to use helvetica letters in math, but not like that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That is interesting, I assumed that unicode-math would use some defaults if these tables are absent. In any case, in the example given above it _does_ work with Helvetica. The only bit missing is to use greek letters from a different font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you use the `\setmathfont` command you should make sure that you also load a real math font as basis. If only text fonts are used in `\setmathfont` you can loose symbols.

The symbol font is not unicode encoded, it has the greek characters at the place of a, b, c etc. So you will need some `\mathgreek` command and will have to redefine `\alpha` etc. You will loose the ability to get a bold alpha with `\symbf{\alpha}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Arial}

\setmathfont{Cambria Math} % a real math font

\setmathfont[range=it/{latin,Latin}]{Arial}

\setmathfontface\mathgreek{Symbol}


\begin{document}

{\fontspec{Symbol} abc}

$\int\sum \mathgreek{abc} \mathit{abc} \alpha\beta\gamma$.

\renewcommand\alpha{\mathord{\mathgreek{a}}}
$\alpha$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. I was not aware of the `mathgreek` command before.

Comment: You couldn't. I invented and defined it with the \setmathfontface command. (You can use another name if you want).